# Concatenating a sequence of std::arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, templates

Consider the following: ([Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/MKM0wqZvWE0vRReD))

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, int N, int M>
auto concat(const std::array<T, N>& ar1, const std::array<T, M>& ar2)
{
    std::array<T, N+M> result;
    std::copy (ar1.cbegin(), ar1.cend(), result.begin());
    std::copy (ar2.cbegin(), ar2.cend(), result.begin() + N);
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 3> ar1 = {1, 2, 3};
    std::array<int, 2> ar2 = {4, 5};
    auto result = concat<int, 3, 2>(ar1, ar2);
    for (auto& x : result)
        std::cout << x << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Given a sequence of `std::array<T, length1>`, `std::array<T, length2>`, ..., `std::array<T, lengthK>`, how can I generalize the above code and write a function which concatenates the sequence into an `std::array<T, sum(lengths)>`?

It would be nice if there is a way to write a reusable function which reduces a similar sequence of template classes using a given binary operation, e.g., use `concat` in the example above, rather than writing a special method (which would have to be re-written each time the binary op changes).

(IIUC, the relevant Standard Library algorithms (`accumulate`, `reduce`) only work in case the class of the result of the binary operation is always the same.)

Comment: We have `std::tuple_cat`. One option is simply writing the conversion from the resulting tuple to an array.

Comment: @chris That's neat, didn't know that function. However as I wrote above it would be nice to have a solution which just applies any given templated binary operation to a sequence of objects of different classes (of course the operation should be associative and valid for applying on all the mid-results)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may do the following:

```
template <typename F, typename T, typename T2>
auto func(F f, T&& t, T2&& t2)
{
    return f(std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<T2>(t2));
}

template <typename F, typename T, typename T2, typename ... Ts>
auto func(F f, T&& t, T2&& t2, Ts&&...args)
{
    return func(f, f(std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<T2>(t2)), std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
}
```

With usage

```
struct concatenater
{
    template<typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
    auto operator()(const std::array<T, N>& ar1, const std::array<T, M>& ar2) const
    {
        std::array<T, N+M> result;
        std::copy (ar1.cbegin(), ar1.cend(), result.begin());
        std::copy (ar2.cbegin(), ar2.cend(), result.begin() + N);
        return result;
    }
};
```

and

```
auto result = func(concatenater{}, ar1, ar2, ar3, ar4);
```

[C++14 Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75705fbc53a7bc28)
[C++11 Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f9bdc5e9e30fad3)

Comment: That's beautiful.

Comment: I believe this is [tag:C++14], [right](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be3a0aa97b39c1db)?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: indeed, missing trailing return type to be C++11. Demo added.

Comment: @Jarod42 Hmm.  For some reason I thought this was a constexpr question.  Ignore me.

Comment: [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) is not `constexpr` until C++20... ;-)

Answer (score 17):

Here is a simple C++17 solution via [fold expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold):

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename Type, std::size_t... sizes>
auto concatenate(const std::array<Type, sizes>&... arrays)
{
    std::array<Type, (sizes + ...)> result;
    std::size_t index{};

    ((std::copy_n(arrays.begin(), sizes, result.begin() + index), index += sizes), ...);

    return result;
}
```

Example of using:

```
const std::array<int, 3> array1 = {{1, 2, 3}};
const std::array<int, 2> array2 = {{4, 5}};
const std::array<int, 4> array3 = {{6, 7, 8, 9}};

const auto result = concatenate(array1, array2, array3);
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e8b49903f4cf63c)

Comment: Beautiful! Any ideas for using a fold expression for a generic version (for an arbitrary binary op)?

Comment: @Danra Generic version wouldn't be so efficient in this case.

Comment: Pretty nice. An underrated answer.

Comment: Beautiful indeed! Can this be constexpr in any sense? On a more general note: are  array algorithms unraveled at compile time?

Comment: @HyperBoar, yes, since C++20 algorithms like [`std::copy_n()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n) are `constexpr`. The methods of `std::array` class are `constexpr` even earlier. So the example mentioned in my answer successfully compiles using the modern versions of g++ and clang++ compilers and the compiler key `-std=c++20`: [Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/n7b71Kd1q).

Answer (score 6):

> Given a sequence of `std::array<T, length1>`, `std::array<T, length2>`, ..., `std::array<T, lengthK>`, how can I write a function which concatenates the sequence into an `std::array<T, sum(lengths)>`?

Here's a C++17 solution. It can very probably be shortened and improved, working on it.

```
template <std::size_t Last = 0, typename TF, typename TArray, typename... TRest>
constexpr auto with_acc_sizes(TF&& f, const TArray& array, const TRest&... rest)
{
    f(array, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Last>{});

    if constexpr(sizeof...(TRest) != 0)
    {
        with_acc_sizes<Last + std::tuple_size_v<TArray>>(f, rest...); 
    }
}

template<typename T, std::size_t... Sizes>
constexpr auto concat(const std::array<T, Sizes>&... arrays)
{
    std::array<T, (Sizes + ...)> result{};

    with_acc_sizes([&](const auto& arr, auto offset)
    {
        std::copy(arr.begin(), arr.end(), result.begin() + offset);
    }, arrays...);

    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
std::array<int, 3> ar1 = {1, 2, 3};
std::array<int, 2> ar2 = {4, 5};
std::array<int, 3> ar3 = {6, 7, 8};
auto result = concat(ar1, ar2, ar3);
```

[**live wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/VA85KCTqxiyS2rKE)

Works with both **g++7** and **clang++5**.

Comment: Here's mine. Feel free to use any part: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/arkvF7HpZGr4LKOa. The only reason I didn't use `std::copy` was to keep it `constexpr`, since that seemed kind of fitting.

Comment: @chris: that's a pretty cool solution - I think you should post it as an answer.

Comment: It's pretty fine where it is considering the OP tagged the question C++11. Because of that, I'd rather keep C++17 improvements in one place.

Comment: My C++17 contribution: perfect forwarding, moving from rvalue inputs instead of copying: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/5O1X7JTAfJ7d40sT BTW your `concat` technically causes UB since no template parameters can ever satisfy `constexpr` requirements (the `constexpr` needs to go because `std::copy` is never `constexpr`).

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Why do you call `f` this way `f(array, std::integral_constant<std::size_t,Las>{})` and not just `f(array,Last)`? Is it to enable constexpr evaluation of `f`?

Comment: @Oliv : Since the callable will be passed an `integral_constant` rather than a `size_t`, it can then use the value in constant expressions (e.g. as a template argument) if desired.

Comment: @ildjarn Yes but C++17 implement constexpr lambda, so after inlining, I was thinking that the generated code would be the exact same. On the other side if their is no inlining of the operator() of the lambda, using Last in the type produces generation of as many operator() as their are array size which could lead to code bloat and will certainly slow down execution since calling multiple time a unique function is really cpu friendly. I have doubts so I am wondering if this is a good pattern or an anti-pattern.

Comment: @Oliv : Function arguments are **never** `constexpr`; this is why it's important to encode the desired value into the type (`integral_constant` in this case). Whether or not the lambda is `constexpr` is 100% orthogonal as to whether or not it might need the value _passed to it as a function argument_ in a constant context.

Comment: @ildjarn Thank you, I really clearly understand what you are talking about. But the argument `offset`, is not involved in any expression which must be constexpr. If you replace `std::integral_constant<size_t,Last>{}` by `Last` the resulting optimized code is exactly the same. Without inlining optimization, the resulting code is smaller if you just use `Last`. Depending on optimizer deciding to inline or not the lambda, the resulting code will be the same or better if you just do not try to help the compiler!

Comment: @Oliv : `with_acc_sizes` appears to be a public interface (based on naming and namespace); just because _`concat`_ doesn't need `offset` as a constant expression doesn't mean it shouldn't be written to accommodate all potential callers correctly. If `with_acc_sizes` were in `namespace detail` or somesuch where we know the _only_ caller is `concat`, then I would fully agree with you. :-]

Comment: @ildjarn, thank you, now I understand your point of view. I had never think about using this kind of "tag-dispatch" like technique for anything but implementation!

Answer (score 3):

My first line of reasoning would be to consider converting the array to a tuple of references (a tie), manipulate with `tuple_cat` and then perform whatever operation is necessary to build the final array (i.e. either move or copy - depending on the arguments originally passed in):

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

namespace detail {
    template<class Array, std::size_t...Is>
    auto array_as_tie(Array &a, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        return std::tie(a[Is]...);
    };

    template<class T, class Tuple, std::size_t...Is>
    auto copy_to_array(Tuple &t, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        return std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)>
                {
                        std::get<Is>(t)...
                };
    };

    template<class T, class Tuple, std::size_t...Is>
    auto move_to_array(Tuple &t, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        return std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)>
                {
                        std::move(std::get<Is>(t))...
                };
    };
}

template<class T, std::size_t N>
auto array_as_tie(std::array<T, N> &a) {
    return detail::array_as_tie(a, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
};


// various overloads for different combinations of lvalues and rvalues - needs some work
// for instance, does not handle mixed lvalues and rvalues yet
template<class T, std::size_t N1, std::size_t N2>
auto array_cat(std::array<T, N1> &a1, std::array<T, N2> &a2) {
    auto tied = std::tuple_cat(array_as_tie(a1), array_as_tie(a2));
    return detail::copy_to_array<T>(tied, std::make_index_sequence<N1 + N2>());
};

template<class T, std::size_t N1, std::size_t N2>
auto array_cat(std::array<T, N1> &&a1, std::array<T, N2> &&a2) {
    auto tied = std::tuple_cat(array_as_tie(a1), array_as_tie(a2));
    return detail::move_to_array<T>(tied, std::make_index_sequence<N1 + N2>());
};

int main() {
    std::array<int, 3> ar1 = {1, 2, 3};
    std::array<int, 2> ar2 = {4, 5};

    auto result = array_cat(ar1, ar2);

    for (auto &x : result)
        std::cout << x << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // move-construction
    auto r2 = array_cat(std::array<std::string, 2> {"a", "b"},
                        std::array<std::string, 2>{"asdfghjk", "qwertyui"});

    std::cout << "string result:\n";
    for (auto &&x : r2)
        std::cout << x << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

expected results:

```
1 2 3 4 5 
string result:
a b asdfghjk qwertyui
```

Answer (score 3):

A more concise evolution of [@Constructor's C++17 solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42774523/14209173) with the added benefit that Type is not required to be default constructible

```
template <typename Type, std::size_t... sizes>
constexpr auto concatenate(const std::array<Type, sizes>&... arrays)
{
    return std::apply(
        [] (auto... elems) -> std::array<Type, (sizes + ...)> { return {{ elems... }}; },
        std::tuple_cat(std::tuple_cat(arrays)...));
}
```

Comment: What's the `std::tuple_cat(std::tuple_cat(arrays)...)` doing?  The inner one looks like it's converting the array into a tuple and the outer one looks like it's concatenating those tuples together.  Then its dumping into an array that has the size of the sum of all the sizes in all of the arrays?  Nice, except...

Comment: ... except that it's not portable. From [tuple_cat](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_cat) *"The behavior is undefined if any type in std::decay_t<Tuples>... is not a specialization of std::tuple. However, an implementation **may choose** to support types (such as std::array and std::pair) that follow the tuple-like protocol."* Which is too bad actually.  Quite elegant.

Answer (score 2):

C++14.

```
template<std::size_t I>
using index_t=std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>;
template<std::size_t I>
constexpr index_t<I> index{};

template<std::size_t...Is>
auto index_over(std::index_sequence<Is...>){
  return [](auto&&f)->decltype(auto){
    return decltype(f)(f)( index<Is>... );
  };
}
template<std::size_t N>
auto index_upto(index_t<N>={}){
  return index_over(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

this lets us expand parameter packs inline.

```
template<std::size_t, class T>
using indexed_type=T;

template<class T>
std::decay_t<T> concat_arrays( T&& in ){ return std::forward<T>(in); }
template<class T, std::size_t N0, std::size_t N1 >
std::array<T, N0+N1>
concat_arrays( std::array<T,N0> arr0, std::array<T,N1> arr1 ){
  auto idx0 = index_upto<N0>();
  auto idx1 = index_upto<N1>();
  return idx0( [&](auto...I0s){
    return idx1( [&](auto...I1s)->std::array<T, N0+N1>{
      return {{
        arr0[I0s]...,
        arr1[I1s]...
      }}; 
    })
  });
}
```

which gets us to two.  For N, the easy way is:

```
template<class T, std::size_t N0, std::size_t N1, std::size_t...Ns >
auto concat_arrays( std::array<T,N0> arr0, std::array<T,N1> arr1, std::array<T, Ns>... arrs ){
  return concat_arrays( std::move(arr0), concat_arrays( std::move(arr1), std::move(arrs)... ) );
}
```

but it should be possible without recursion.

Code not tested.

Answer (score 2):

C++17 solution that is `constexpr` and works correctly with moveably-only types.

```
template<class Array>
inline constexpr auto array_size = std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_reference_t<Array>>;

template<typename... Ts>
constexpr auto make_array(Ts&&... values)
{
    using T = std::common_type_t<Ts...>;
    return std::array<T, sizeof...(Ts)>{static_cast<T>(std::forward<Ts>(values))...};
}

namespace detail
{
template<typename Arr1, typename Arr2, std::size_t... is1, std::size_t... is2>
constexpr auto array_cat(Arr1&& arr1, Arr2&& arr2, std::index_sequence<is1...>, std::index_sequence<is2...>)
{
    return make_array(std::get<is1>(std::forward<Arr1>(arr1))...,
        std::get<is2>(std::forward<Arr2>(arr2))...);
}
}

template<typename Arr, typename... Arrs>
constexpr auto array_cat(Arr&& arr, Arrs&&... arrs)
{
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Arrs) == 0)
        return std::forward<Arr>(arr);
    else if constexpr (sizeof...(Arrs) == 1)
        return detail::array_cat(std::forward<Arr>(arr), std::forward<Arrs>(arrs)...,
            std::make_index_sequence<array_size<Arr>>{},
            std::make_index_sequence<array_size<Arrs...>>{});
    else
        return array_cat(std::forward<Arr>(arr), array_cat(std::forward<Arrs>(arrs)...));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Strictly C++11; not as readable as @Jarod42's, but potentially much more efficient with many arrays if the call-tree isn't fully flattened (in terms of inlining) since only one result object exists rather than multiple temporary, progressively-growing result objects:

```
namespace detail {
    template<std::size_t...>
    struct sum_sizes_;

    template<std::size_t Acc>
    struct sum_sizes_<Acc> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Acc> { };

    template<std::size_t Acc, std::size_t N, std::size_t... Ns>
    struct sum_sizes_<Acc, N, Ns...> : sum_sizes_<Acc + N, Ns...> { };

    template<typename... As>
    using sum_sizes_t = typename sum_sizes_<
        0, std::tuple_size<typename std::decay<As>::type>{}...
    >::type;

    template<std::size_t O, typename A, typename R>
    void transfer(R& ret, typename std::remove_reference<A>::type const& a) {
        std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), ret.begin() + O);
    }

    template<std::size_t O, typename A, typename R>
    void transfer(R& ret, typename std::remove_reference<A>::type&& a) {
        std::move(a.begin(), a.end(), ret.begin() + O);
    }

    template<std::size_t, typename R>
    void concat(R const&) { }

    template<std::size_t O, typename R, typename A, typename... As>
    void concat(R& ret, A&& a, As&&... as) {
        transfer<O, A>(ret, std::forward<A>(a));
        concat<(O + sum_sizes_t<A>{})>(ret, std::forward<As>(as)...);
    }
}

template<typename... As, typename std::enable_if<(sizeof...(As) >= 2), int>::type = 0>
auto concat(As&&... as)
-> std::array<
    typename std::common_type<typename std::decay<As>::type::value_type...>::type,
    detail::sum_sizes_t<As...>{}
> {
    decltype(concat(std::forward<As>(as)...)) ret;
    detail::concat<0>(ret, std::forward<As>(as)...);
    return ret;
}
```

<kbd>**[Online Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b6ffd768b2b6125)**</kbd>

Note that this also forwards properly by using the [`std::move` algorithm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) for rvalues rather than `std::copy`.

Comment: You can remove `typename` and `::type` in the `using sum_sizes_t =`... line

Comment: @Danra : I have them there on purpose. :-] Removing them would work here in this context but I prefer my metafunctions to return exactly `std::integral_constant` rather than a derived type so they can be used with specialization and not just SFINAE.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't generalize, but takes advantage of the fact that if we splat two arrays inside a set of braces, we can use that to initialize a new array.

I'm not sure how useful generalizing is, in any case. Given a bunch of arrays of mismatched sizes, just what else is there to do with them but join them all together?

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template<typename T, std::size_t L, std::size_t... Ls,
                     std::size_t R, std::size_t... Rs>
constexpr std::array<T, L + R> concat_aux(const std::array<T, L>& l, std::index_sequence<Ls...>,
                                          const std::array<T, R>& r, std::index_sequence<Rs...>) {
    return std::array<T, L + R> { std::get<Ls>(l)..., std::get<Rs>(r)... };
}

template<typename T, std::size_t L, std::size_t R>
constexpr std::array<T, L + R> concat(const std::array<T, L>& l, const std::array<T, R>& r) {
    return concat_aux(l, std::make_index_sequence<L>{},
                      r, std::make_index_sequence<R>{});
}

template<typename T, std::size_t L, std::size_t R, std::size_t... Sizes>
constexpr auto concat(const std::array<T, L>& l,
                      const std::array<T, R>& r,
                      const std::array<T, Sizes>&... arrays) {
    return concat(concat(l, r), arrays...);
}

int main() {
    std::array<int, 5> a1{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::array<int, 3> a2{6, 7, 8};
    std::array<int, 2> a3{9, 10};

    for (const auto& elem : concat(a1, a2, a3)) {
        std::cout << elem << " ";
    }
}
```